# Application of Epistemology to Robotics or other machine-based "exploration" systems?

Tags: epistemology, artificial-intelligence

So, as [epistemology](/questions/tagged/epistemology) is the main branch of philosophy dealing with knowledge, it would be reasonable to assume that (multiple) people tried to apply ideas from it to practical knowlegde-accumulating systems, including autonomous robots and scanners.

Yet, it does not seem to be the case, at least on the surface.

---

Question:

**Is there any good example of attempt to use epistemological apparatus in practice ?** Or maybe a book where such application is suggested ?

Comment: Epistemology is more about justifying knowledge than accumulating it, so it is not really useful for learning robots, the [theory of cognition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/innateness-cognition/) is much more so. But look at [Dreyfus's Why Heideggerian AI Failed](http://leidlmair.at/doc/WhyHeideggerianAIFailed.pdf) for the parts of it that AI researchers were interested in.

Comment: Thank you @Conifold